Skip test with warning in Rust?
I want to create a unit test that runs, checks an external status, and possibly returns early, skipping the test. But I DON'T want that to count as a failure: it's just a skipped test. And if I just return Ok(()), that's a success, which I don't want either. I want the user to be clearly informed that a test was skipped, but that otherwise everything is fine. I can do this in Dart.
The particular circumstances are these: one unit test requires that a file of test data be built, and building that file requires a tool my user might not have. So when he runs the test, I want him clearly informed that a test was skipped because this file was not present, and that he should install the tool and build the file, but that otherwise nothing is wrong, and if he doesn't want to install the tool, that's his choice.
I'd be OK with counting the test a success if I could get some message to the user through the output capture.

@cdhowie The linked question has a very similar title, but ultimately it's not a dupe since that asker was just looking for a way to print non-captured output to the terminal.

To be fair, though, the other question did give me close enough to a solution for my needs.

@JohnKugelman Conceptually they are the same question. OP of the other question posed their own workaround idea, which was supplied in an answer. IMO the answer there is the best one can do today, anyway, since Rust doesn't have a way for a test to mark itself "skipped" by logic in the test function itself.
